# Background process - can't find it - a program

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a program - keyboard layout program. Starting when I start my computer. I have deactivated startup items. I can't find the - keyboard layout program - since it has not installed a shortcut on 'start menu'.

This program is running in background - in my win 7 computer - BUT IT doesn't show in task manager, or in startup items.

Screenshot of preferences when I look at the language input settings.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Its not possible for a program to be running on Windows and for process or service NOT to be listed.  Lets start with a screenshot of said program.

Comment: I probably sound like a dumb man. Perhaps so. BUT I DON'T READ FINNISH! This seem to me - beeing my main problem. - I've btw kept my finnish settings 1. since they work. 2. since I like finnish language. And plan to learn it (I know 5 languages, but not finnish).

Comment: Please clarify your comment.  But you can simply select the keyboard in question and hit `Remove`.

Comment: OK. If you open 'add input language'. Do you find setting 'workman' or is this only on my computer?

Comment: Thats only on your computer you added that keyboard layout.

Comment: I don't remember doing so but I'm sure you are right. I remember installing a addon program that could change keyboard layout. because I changed from using a Mac. To windows. But the 'Workman Programmer' layout i could not find anywhere on the internet. Beleve me I tried.

Comment: You say "BUT I DON'T READ FINNISH!". If there is any Finnish on the screen you selected Finnish as a **display** language. This is different from the setting of keyboard layout. Check "Clock, Language and Region" and check which language is selected as **display**-language.

Comment: @Rik I, by misstake selected finnish, because I was trying the keyboard. You could select between English and 4 of the nordic languages (or choose one from a list). I now found a better 'change language guide'. I am trying it now. Be back soon.

Comment: @r4. - The screenshots you choose are the only windows you should be looking at.

Comment: @Ramhound - No - Because. What I really did was to use a program. This program automatically installed (it required permission, of course) this Workman layout. I did not download the workman layout. This program that installed this was downloaded from the internet. // lesson to be learned - keep better order of ''' all programs you have downloaded (if I kept track of my old files it would be too much). // OR EVEN BETTER - USE LINUX ! no windows for programming, but then again, I do use windows...

Comment: --- I think I am the only one who can really answer for how I did this (i.e. what the name of this external program is). Voting for close.

Comment: --- No I changed my mind. My original question was (as far as I am concerned) answered by mr Allquisotic. Accepted this answer. Because he describes in great detail how to deal with this.

Comment: --- I had to rephrase my question in order to be more 'clear'. If you want to see my question. Use rollback.

Comment: @r4. - You didn't use a third-party program. You can customize the keyboard within Windows. Your screenshots even prove you did exactly that. to get the default behavior back, just remove the custom keyboard layout.

Comment: You do know that if you want the "Workman Keyboard Layout" you can just download it [here](http://www.workmanlayout.com/blog/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My typical approach to trying to locate an unknown background program running on Windows 7 or Windows 8:

1. Go to Start -> Run (or press the key combination <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and type `services.msc` and click OK
2. Look down the list of services to see if any look familiar (product name, type of program, intended purpose, etc.)
3. Try to **stop** a service that you suspect might be the problem, as long as it doesn't contain "Microsoft" or "Windows" in the name, or give you a warning that it might make your system unstable if you stop it, or stop other services along with it. **Don't** stop things like "Desktop Window Manager", "Netlogon", "Workstation", "Plug and Play", etc.
4. If you can't locate the background task under Services: go to Start -> Run (or press the key combination <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and type `taskmgr` and click OK
5. In Task Manager, go to "Processes" (Windows 7) or "Details" (Windows 8).
6. Look for tasks that have executable names that contain some sort of indication of the program you might be looking for. If you aren't sure about an executable, you can right-click on it and select `Open File Location`. This will open up Windows Explorer in the directory where the executable resides. Look at the name of the folder -- does it look familiar? Do you recognize the product name or vendor name?
7. In general, if the executable is in `C:\Windows` or a subfolder thereof, it's a critical system task by Microsoft, and shouldn't be terminated. You can *try*, but back up your work before you do so, because it may make your system unstable. Alternatively you might just get an `Access denied` error if you try to stop a critical system process.

If all of these steps fail, then the program you're looking for is not actively running; it may simply apply some settings and then exit. To locate programs of this sort:

1. Go to Start -> Run (or press the key combination <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and type `msconfig` and click OK.
2. Click the `Startup` tab. Look for programs listed there that might be your culprit.

Comment: `Procmon` and `Autoruns` are both helpful programs to do what `allquixotic` describes.

Comment: Kind of you to help. But now I've updated my question. Tried some of your tips already.